# 1960s light switch issue wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety, light

If the top bracket in the image here came out and didn’t go back in, would it be a safety issue to turn the circuit back on? There was no wire connected to the screw/bracket — it seemed to just be holding those two bundles of wire against the back.....

We can’t get an electrician for a few days and I’m nervous. The house is from 1962 and this (I think) is original.

[image]

Comment: Basically a wire/cable clamp to keep cables from moving.  Should have outer cable covering in more, instead of just inner wires on bottom edge.  Why did it not go back in?  Minor safely issue, unless idiots, kids, or monkeys hanging on wires.  Remove completely or replaced/put back in.

Comment: Yes, why did that cableclamp not go back in?

Answer (score 1):

the screw should thread directly into the wall of the box (there is no nut that may have fell away). To check that the screw isn't stripped try turning it without the wire bracket in place. If it doeesn't want to thread in easily look at the screw threads and confirm they are intact and not stripped or damaged.

If they look damaged replace with a new "round head machine screw". I believe the thread size is a 10-32 x 1 inch (it may be 8/32?). Bring it to the hardware store and match it.

If the threads are damaged on the back of the box purchase a self-threading screw slightly bigger and drill it into the original hole.

If you'd rather not attempt the repair your self (always good to know limitations) there is a very low chance of any hazards occurring until an electrician arrives. the clamp is used to prevent the cable from being yanked out of the box and there is probably a cable staple close to the box as back-up.

Comment: I just checked a couple the grounding screw is 10-32 but the clamp screw on the boxes I have are 8-32 i don’t think there is a standard on that size so checking is a good idea.